# Swift Json count and create TableView

Tags: ios, json, swift

I need to create a tableview and fill that with database information that I take with json. This is the response I get from the database with json

```
 {
"news": [
    {
        "id": "35",
        "type": "news",
        "title": "final test for offer",
        "city": "Mumbai",
        "description": "Test description",
        "image": "http://www.saimobileapp.com/mobileappbackend/news/IMG_0421.JPG"
    },
    {
        "id": "31",
        "type": "news",
        "title": "new test",
        "city": "Mumbai",
        "description": "yes its a test msg",
        "image": "http://www.saimobileapp.com/mobileappbackend/news/Chrysanthemum.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": "30",
        "type": "news",
        "title": "This is a test news",
        "city": "Mumbai",
        "description": "Test description",
        "image": "http://www.saimobileapp.com/mobileappbackend/news/1.jpg"
    }
]
}
```

These are 3 different news with title etc., so I need to count it as I will add new, and create a table view in base of that.

This is my code now to get the database information with new EDIT:

```
    func LoadNews() {


    let post:NSString = ""

    NSLog("PostData: %@",post);

    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://saimobileapp.com/services/sai_news.php")!

    let postData:NSData = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!

    let postLength:NSString = String( postData.length )

    let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = postData
    request.setValue(postLength as String, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")


    var reponseError: NSError?
    var response: NSURLResponse?

    var urlData: NSData? = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response, error:&reponseError)

    if ( urlData != nil ) {
        let res = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse!;

        NSLog("Response code: %ld", res.statusCode);
        if (res.statusCode >= 200 && res.statusCode < 300)
        {
            let responseData:NSString  = NSString(data:urlData!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

            NSLog("Response ==> %@", responseData);

            var error: NSError?

                         var Title: [String] = []

            if let jsonData = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options: nil, error: &error) as? [String:AnyObject] { // dictionary
                if let locationsArray = jsonData["news"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] { // array of dictionaries
                    for locationDictionary in locationsArray { // we loop in the array of dictionaries
                        if let location = locationDictionary["title"] as? String { // finally, access the dictionary like you were trying to do

                            Title.append(location)

                            var SaveTitle = save.setObject(Title, forKey: "NewsTitle")

                        }
                    }
                }
            }










        }




    }


}
```

And for TableView i use that now :

```
    // MARK:  UITextFieldDelegate Methods
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

   var FormName = save.arrayForKey("NewsTitle")!

    return FormName.count
}







func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var FormName = save.arrayForKey("NewsTitle")!

    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.TableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! UITableViewCell

    let row = indexPath.row

    cell.textLabel?.text = FormName[indexPath.row] as! String





    if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }else{

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        cell.textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.0)
    }




    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    return cell

}
// MARK:  UITableViewDelegate Methods
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    TableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)

    let row = indexPath.row
```

How can i show the description in the second page when i tap on the cell?

Can anyone please help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps to render your table view:

Assuming you have set your view controller as datasource and delegate for UITableViewController.

1. In your table view controller' subclass: inside loadView or viewWillAppear make server call to fetch the details. [This you might already be doing]
2. Create a global parameter to hold to that data. e.g. `self.vehicles = jsonData["news"]`
3. After server response, call `reloadData`method on `self.tableView`. This will trigger calls to your table data sources methods - `numberOfRowsInSection:`, `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` etc.
4. Return correct values from data source methods. Based on your needs you can create a custom cell and use `self.vehicles` to fetch & render data on it.

**Edit:**
**Example**

Your data is a array of dictionary where array count will drive the number of cells in the table. That said, lets say there are 5 dictionaries in your array so you have 5 cells. When you get a call on `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, use 'index path.row' to get the right dictionary mapped to the cell in request. Now, fetch the values inside that dictionary and set them on cell. Like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell? {
    // Configure the cell...
    let cellId: NSString = "Cell"
    var cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellId) as UITableViewCell

    if let ip = indexPath {
        var data = self.vehicles[ip.row] as NSDictionary
        cell.textLabel.text = data.valueForKey("title") as String
    }

    return cell
}
```

Similarly implement `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and then fetch & pass on description to your target view controller for display.

**Edit 2 (On OP request):**

Based on second screen design (table controller or simple view controller), create a new controller class. Then, as I mentioned above, implement `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` something like below:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var description = String()

    if let ip = indexPath {
        var data = self.vehicles[ip.row] as NSDictionary
        description = data.valueForKey("description") as String
    }

    var descriptionVC = SecondScreenVC(withDescription: description)
    self.navigationController.pushViewController(descriptionVC, animated: true)
}
```

Some references:

[Apple Docs on UITableViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewController_Class/)

[Handling UITableViewController Programmatically](http://www.sixpacksumo.com/ios-lesson-4-uitableviewcontroller-programmatically/)

Comment: sorry i'm not an expert of tableview.. i can create one but i don't understand the steps

Comment: Basically, `[self.tableView reloadData]` is the key here. After you receive data from server call this and then whatever basic knowledge you have about UITableViews, convert it into code and you should be able to render it. I have updated my post with couple of links which you might have already gone through but just for reference in case of need.

Comment: the problem here is how get the different news and put it in the table view, so how can i get like the title for all the news and put it as the title of the tableview

Comment: Can you please briefly explain where you want to put all this data. For instance title will be on each cell `textLabel`, description would be on each cell `detailTextLabel` etc.

Comment: the description will be in another page when you tap on the cell

Comment: Thank you, while you was reply i was updating my code, in fact now my tableview create successful as cell as the news with the proper title, but now how can i create the second page when i tap on the news?

Answer (score 1):

The object of key `news` is an `Array` (of dictionaries), not a `Dictionary`

```
if let vehicles = jsonData["news"] as? NSArray {
   for vehicle in vehicles {
      let vehiclesKeys = vehicle.allKeys
         println(vehiclesKeys)
         println("123")
        }
    }
}
```

`vehicles.count` gives you the number of items in the array.

Comment: thank you very much and do you know also how i can put all information on the table view ??

Comment: put the value of `vehicles` into an instance variable as data source, implement `UITableViewDataSource` protocol with the required methods, there are millions of tutorials how to populate a table view in iOS

Comment: yes yes i know how to create a tableview but this is more complicated cause i need to create as cell as the news